# click function in react

Tags: reactjs, function, onclick, clickonce

## How to apply Click function in React

You can try to use this in your react file to active any click handler

```
    class YourClass extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          show: false,
          position: 0,
          menuoPen: "setDefault"
        };
      }

      onmEnuBtnClick = () => {
        this.setState({
          menuoPen: "setOnClick"
        });
      };

      render() {
        const { show, position, menuoPen } = this.state;
        return (
            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.onmEnuBtnClick()}>
                News
             </button>
              )
           }
        }


    export default YourClass ;
```

click function in react

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: The `onClick` handler is for actual HTML elements like `<div>`. If you pass it to a component like you're doing with `Link`, you still need to attach it to the outer HTML element in that `Link` component

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this: onClick={() => this.onmEnuBtnClick()}
You must be changed onClick={() => this.onmEnuBtnClick()} to

```js
onClick={onmEnuBtnClick}
```

I hope this helps you.